# Using database class with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, database-connection

The classic first liner - have seen similar questions on SO but none that truly help me understand the crossroads I am at.

A little background before the code - I am not new to PHP or PDO (though not an expert either), but am a complete newbie to Object Oriented PHP and am trying to get the balance right of when to use classes and when it is possibly overkill.

The answer I'm hoping is in two parts. Firstly, it is good practice to create a wrapper database class when using PDO - for connection, basic queries etc.

Secondly, if not - are there better ways to speed up query writing?

**EDIT** Whilst I am questioning the code below, really I am question the PDO wrapper class approach overall - so the class below could be much larger than this, but is there any need/benefit?

See the following code;
**NOTE**: The class file is called via spl_autoload_register() in config.php

**class_database.php**

```
class Database
{
    private $conn;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->openConnection();
    }

    public function openConnection() {
        try {
            $this->conn = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_SERVER . '; dbname=' . DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
            $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo 'There was an error connecting to the database, Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            die();
        }
    }

    public function getAll($sql, array $params) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($params);
        return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
}
```

**generic_file.php**

```
require_once '../includes/config.php';
$dbh = new Database();

$sql = ("SELECT * FROM users where id = :id and username = :username");
$id = 1;
$username = 'craig';
$params = array(':id' => $id,
                ':username' => $username);
$row = $dbh->getAll($sql, $params);
var_dump($row);
```

Now, to me this seems totally pointless. Using PDO alone, not a wrapper class, this query would be just as simple to write. On top of this - what if I want to use different fetch methods - I'd have to write more methods in the class.
Also, previously I have used a simple function to instantiate and return a new PDO object, simply including that file and assigning a variable to the function return was simple as quick - again I feel the class method is overkill.

Also, with my code above, and by doing this in a class, am I not losing the benefit of 'preparing' the statement as I will have to pass the sql statement in each time, even just to change the variables for the same statement?

However, I find lots of examples online, and especially on Lynda.com which I am using currently, of database wrapper classes. On top of this - I am no expert, and therefore what I feel is overkill may actually be best practice and strongly recommended, hence looking to you SO experts to help me out!

So...back to my question - is there a good reason to use such a class when using PDO?
If not, is there another DRY method that others use to minimize lines of codes needed for queries using PDO?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I personally think PDO is slim enough to use without wrappers.

Comment: PDO is a database abstraction class itself so I agree with your thinking that it is offering nothing but additional complexity to wrap it in another class that exposes almost an identical api.

Comment: The only real motivation for doing this is if you are going to abstract away the database to the point you can provide a mock to your classes for unit testing.

Comment: While not a necessity in this case, wrapper classes do provide a more modular system that allows you to build out a big class, refine, tweak and reuse by dropping into another project.  It gives you more control (using one file) on what sql functions you want to use which could be beneficial down the road. Maybe you want to even change your sql engine or driver for example.

Comment: so you mean your most used sql queries for example?

Comment: A library like Doctrine DBAL adds something useful on top of PDO, but such a simple wrapper like the one in your example offers nothing.

Comment: There's no definitive right or wrong answer to this. Much will depend on your circumstances and your personal opinion. Ergo, this is off-topic here.

Comment: See, you don't have to keep creating the connection anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I had your same question at one time.

The benefit to abstracting the database away is you can assure all connections are made correctly and if you ever do need to change the type of database there is only one spot that you need to change the code for. It also makes it easier to check the queries issued because you know if you echo and exit in the class all of the queries will able to be checked.

The way I solved it was by creating a class where the constructer established the connection and assigned it to a private variable while also setting the table in the database too.
The best way is to then have a few public functions to create, retrieve, update, and delete. Which is sometimes called CRUD.
For each function the only and first parameter is an array. For creating it takes the array and creates a prepared statement with it and then executes it.
It does a very similar thing with the others but for retrieve the array is what is being matched, for update it takes the things ending in id and sets the rest to update where the id = provided, and for delete it deletes where all of the keys = value in the table.

EDIT:
Here is the delete function I put in the class. If one of the parameter's values is an array it will prepare the statement and cycle through it. That is only for one variable changing though. You could also have it where you pass an array with the values of the numerical indexes being an array of what you would want to insert though that is not how I set up my code.

```
public function delete($info) {
    $dbh = $this->dbh;

    if (isset($info['submit_action'])) unset($info['submit_action']);
    $where = array();
    foreach (array_keys($info) as $name) {
        $where[] .= "$name = :$name";
    }
    //echo "DELETE FROM {$this->table_name} WHERE " . implode(" AND ", $where) . ";"; exit;
    $data = $dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM {$this->table_name} WHERE " . implode(" AND ", $where) . ";");
    foreach ($info as $name => $value) {
        if ($array_value == $name) $data->bindParam(":$name", $array_info);
        else $data->bindValue(":$name", trim($value));
    }

    foreach ($info as $name => $value) if (is_array($value)) { $array_value = $name; break; }
    if (isset($array_value)) {

        foreach ($info[$array_value] as $array_info) {
            try {
                $data->execute();
            }
            catch (PDOException $e) {
                if (!is_null($this->error_msg))
                    handle_error($this->error_msg, $e->getMessage());
                else
                handle_error("There was a problem removing the {$this->subject}.", $e->getMessage());
            }
        }

    } else {
        try {
            $data->execute();
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            handle_error(/*public error msg - could set this anyway you want*/, $e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    // Send success msg
}
```

Comment: Great that makes sense thanks. When you say it only takes an array - what about the sql statement? Is this not too inflexible to have the sql set a the class level or do you mean the most popular queries, then would you write some more obscure ones from scratch in place in a file rather than using the class every time?

Comment: another point - with my code above, and by doing this in  a class, am I not losing the benefit of 'preparing' the statement as I will have to pass the sql statement in each time, even just to change the variables for the same statement?